# DependencyProperty change doesn't trigger an arrange

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom panel, which defines this dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DragPositionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DragPosition",
    typeof(Point),
    typeof(LogViewHeaderPanel),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new Point(),
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange
    )
);
```

Note: I've tried with FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange as well...

That LogViewHeaderPanel is the panel for my custom ItemsControl called LogViewHeader.  Its items are of type ColumnHeader.  Whenever the mouse is moved, and a few other conditions are met within the LogViewHeader, the target ColumnHeader has the property set using the following code:

```
_currentlyActiveColumnHeader.SetValue(
    LogViewHeaderPanel.DragPositionProperty,
    new Point(suggestedXPosition, originalPosition.Y)
);
```

If I put a breakpoint on my override for LogViewHeaderPanel.ArrangeOverride, I can see it gets called when the LogViewHeader is created/resized, but not when the DragPosition property is set on it's child.

Why is the FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange parameter not triggering an arrange when the property is set?

Comment: You are setting the `DragPosition` property on `_currentlyActiveColumnHeader`, which I guess is not a `LogViewHeaderPanel`. Although I'm not sure if it matters here, you would have to register `DragPosition` as an attached property for this kind of use. Just replace `DependencyProperty.Register` by `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.

Comment: And also note the [Remarks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsparentarrange.aspx): `Generally, you do not need to report changes of a FrameworkElement property to a parent element using AffectsParentArrange because the element itself would already have its own AffectsArrange as true. That is usually sufficient, because changes in the child element generally initiate a parent arrange when appropriate.`

Comment: @Clemens Thanks that worked.  The property is used solely for layout purposes by the panel, it does not affect any other properties on the child itself which may then propagate layout changes.  I'm using this technique to do a "visual" drag-drop, similar to moving around browser tabs, both the built-in DoDragDrop and Adorner functionality wouldn't (to my knowledge) give the same visual effect.  Or am I going about this totally the wrong way?

Comment: Doesn't look like the totally wrong way. I'm going to write the RegisterAttached thing as an answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `DragPosition` property on `_currentlyActiveColumnHeader`, which is not a `LogViewHeaderPanel`. For this kind of use you have to register `DragPosition` as an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just replace `DependencyProperty.Register` by `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DragPositionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DragPosition", typeof(Point), typeof(LogViewHeaderPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new Point(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
```